# Foundation 6 Top Bar Menu Icon

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Was just getting into Foundation 5 and then 6 comes out.  Now I am having trouble with the Top Bar menu code.  Specifically, when I resize my browser from large to medium size, I want the top menu options to disappear and the menu-icon (hamburger) to appear.  When I click on the hamburger icon, the nav links appear vertically.  This worked in 5 but I cannot figure it out in 6.

What I have so far - minus the menu-icon code.  This works and the top-bar shows on my page with the links.

```
<div class="top-bar">
    <div class="top-bar-left">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li class="menu-text"> >> </li>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="apartment-descriptions.html">Apartment Descriptions</a></li>
          <li><a href="floorplans.html">FloorPlans</a></li>
          <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a></li>
          <li><a href="application.html">Application</a></li>
          <li><a href="lease.html">Our Lease</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I found one solution that worked, but the entire page disappears until I click on a menu link - weird.

Would anyone be able to tell me what I need to do?  Or, point me to a good tutorial that shows how to add the menu-icon?

Thanks for the help, as always.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="top-bar">
          <div class="top-bar-left">
            <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="small">
              <span class="menu-icon dark" data-toggle></span>
            </span>
          </div>
          <div id="responsive-menu">
            <div class="top-bar-section">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li class="title"><a class="title-link" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="title"><a class="title-link" href="#events">EVENTS</a></li>
                    <li class="title"><a class="title-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

In large and medium screens your links will appear horizontal.
And you can achieve the vertical links on small devices by using a `jQuery.browser.mobile`script:

**JS**:

```
(function(a){(jQuery.browser=jQuery.browser||{}).mobile=/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);

if (jQuery.browser.mobile) {
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        $(".menu").addClass("vertical");
    });

    $(function () {
    $('.title-link').on('click', function () {

        $("#responsive-menu").css({"display": "none"});

    });
});

}
jQuery(document).foundation();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If using Foundation 6.2.4 be sure to use data-hide-for="medium"  as using 'small' does not work.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is with the "hamburger icon"? This code should be helpful:

```
<div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Source: [foundation-forum](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/36228-foundation-6-topbar-like-f5)

Also try to change your `ul` class to:

```
<ul class="dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-dropdown-menu>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, appreciated.  I now have two rows.  Top row is black with menu-icon and "Menu" text.  This does nothing.  2nd row has my nav links.  Using FF responsive design view, when I narrow my screen to about 639, my nav links become stacked.  In Foundation 5, the menu-icon was hidden until my screensize hit small.  Then, nav links disappeared and menu-icon appeared.  Clicking menu-icon the nav links appeared vertically stacked.  If I cannot get that functionallity, I can make it work without the menu-icon.